# Illegal Characters in Password in Expect / Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect, heredoc

We are having a password which is `` bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!\`fr,./&##@ `` (Except the quotes). This password contains characters such as `{`, `` ` ``, `/`, `.`, `!` which might need to be escaped.  A lot of combinations have been tried to no avail and after spending a lot of time trying to fix this issue, the following snippet is not working.

Already tried:

- `` 'bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!`fr,./&##@'"\r" ``
- `` "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!`fr,./&##@\r" ``
- `` "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0"'!'"`fr,./&##@\r" ``
- `` 'bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!`fr,./&##@\r' ``
- `` "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!\`fr,./&##@\r" ``
- `` "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!\`fr,./&##@\r" ``

---

Start of Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn scp user111@servername.domain.com:/home/path1/test1.log /home/path2/
expect {
    " password: " { send 'bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!`fr,./&##@'"\r";  exp_continue }
    eof
}
... some code ...
EOF
```

How can I get this password into `expect`?

Comment: Escape backticks with \.

Comment: Not working with "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!\`fr,./&##@\r"
missing close-brace
    while executing
"expect {
    " password: " { send "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!`fr,./&##@\r";  exp_continue }
    eof
}


"

Comment: try declaring the password first, with set password "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!`fr,./&##@"; and then send "$password\r"

Comment: the problem may be due to quote missing arround bash here-doc delimiter EOF compare `cat <<'EOF'` and `cat <<EOF` in first variables are not expanded whereas in second are

Comment: I tried this and use \` for "`" and it pasted the wrong password
set password "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!`fr,./&##@";
send "$password\r"

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First line

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
```

must be changed to

```
/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF'
```

The main issue is due to how bash process here-doc

> ```
>       <<[-]word
>                   here-document
>           delimiter
>
>   ...  If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is
>   the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter  expansion,
>    command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \<newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.
> ```

Comment: @BejoyM, please note that single quotes have no meaning in Tcl: they are just plain characters. use `{braces}` in Tcl -- they have the same purpose as shell single quotes: grouping of words without interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Making this as a seperate file and using expect command worked:

```
set password "bt67nJuse3?{]=_0!\`fr,./&##@";
spawn scp user111@servername.domain.com:/home/path1/test1.log /home/path2/
expect {
    " password: " { send "$password\r";  exp_continue }
    eof
}
```

and Using "expect fileName" worked!!! WOW OMG